# Alfresco activiti mail.execute taking too much time

Tags: email, workflow, alfresco, activiti

We are working on an issue related to sending mails from activiti workflow engine, embedded in Alfresco as part of a user task. When there about 20 users in the reviewerGroup (refer the following code block) system is taking too much time and user has to wait about 2 to 3 minutes in the UI until the mails are all sent. If it takes more than 2 minutes, the user is given timeout error in the UI and exceptions are thrown in the Alfresco console. I am including the block of code sending the mail to a group of users. reviewerGroup contains set of users.

```
mail.parameters.template_model = templateModel;
mail.parameters.to_many = reviewerGroup;
mail.parameters.subject = "Your group has content to review in "+sourceEnv;
mail.parameters.from = people.getPerson("alfresco_noreply").properties.email;
mail.parameters.template = emailReviewTemplate;
mail.execute(bpm_package);
```

Can anyone suggest any optimizations we can do to improve or fix this workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple fix would be to send the mail asynchronously, so that the action call returns immediately and the sending occurs in another thread. The only downside of this is that the calling code won't be notified if the sending fails (though you can attach a compensating action for failure handling if you wanted)

To do that, simply change the line:

```
 mail.execute(bpm_package);
```

For:

```
mail.executeAsynchronously(bpm_package);
```

See the [Alfresco JavaScript docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-ScriptAction-executeAsynchronously.html) for more on this

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the issue. Workflows are executing in one to two seconds now.

Comment: Glad that helped! It's normal here to click the "tick" next to an answer to mark it as accepted, to show everyone else that an answer was the correct one - see the [Help Center and Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info!